# how can I pass List<int> into a varargs method

Tags: java, int, variadic-functions

hi I have a method using varargs

```java
public void methodA(int... is);
```

And I'd like to put a List into it like this

```java
List<Integer> listOfIds = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
methodA(listOfIds);
```

how can I do ? ps: I tried this Using Arrays.stream(listOfIds).boxed().Collector.toArray( Integer[]::new ); but java told me `Cannot resolve method 'stream(java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>)'`

Comment: There is no such thing as `List<int>` in Java.

Comment: Specifically you should use the answer from the duplicate that utilizes Java 8 streams AKA `methodA(listOfIds.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray())` which converts the `List` into `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`.

Comment: `listOfIds` is a `List`, so why are you trying to treat it as an array by calling `Arrays.stream()`? You're doing it the wrong way. Use `listOfIds.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray()` instead, as shown in the duplicate answer.